# Load models in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I tried to search here before creating this, but I couldn't find anything.

I have a simple project without modules and I'd like to load my models (which are inside *application/models*) without using any namespace and without usign any extra loading lines.

Basically what I want to do is to have my `class Projects extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` inside my *models* folder and to load it in my controller using `$db = new Projects();`

Is there anyway to do this? Is it recommended to use Model_Projects instead?

What If I had modules?

### Edit:

I tried to use this without any other implementation and I got `Class 'Projects' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the Projects class is not autoloaded. Depending on your application namespace, (for example the default namespace 'Default') you have to name your class into something like: **Default_Model_Projects**

Comment: how do I define my application namespace? Remember that I'm not using modules

Comment: Application namespace can be set at config, ex: appNamespace = "Default"